# Material UI - Table Pagination is zero-based index, how to make it non-zero

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material UI Table pagination is zero-indexed, which means if I am on `page 1`, it will go back to `page 0`. How can I enforce to stop at `page 1`?

[image]

I try passing something like this, `page={pageNumber || 1}`, but it still calls `onChangePage`. Even though it does not try to load `Page 0`, but still its bad User Experience. You expect the previous button to be disabled in the below screenshot,

[image]

https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/#tablepagination-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I have the best solution, but I make it work, by subtracting `-1` when feeding to `page={pageNumber - 1}`, and add `+1` when `onChangePage = (e, pageNumber) => {..pageNumber + 1}` is called.